# How to disable the spamming of routine messages from y/p/u commands?

Tags: vim, neovim

I work many hours a day with text and find all those messages about how many lines of code I copied/restored, and so on, quite useless and distracting. Is there a way to disable them in `neovim`? I know about the `:h report` command, but it seems to me that it doesn't work with `undo`.

Comment: There's `report` and `shortmess`, but I don't think the latter has any options for what you're looking for, although you could try them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [`<silent>` map](https://neovim.io/doc/user/map.html#%3Amap-silent) to call [`:normal`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/various.html#%3Anormal) using [`:silent`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/various.html#%3Asilent).

```
nnoremap <silent> p :silent normal! p<CR>
nnoremap <silent> P :silent normal! P<CR>
nnoremap <silent> y :silent normal! y<CR>
nnoremap <silent> u :silent normal! u<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-r> :silent normal! <C-v><C-r><CR>
```

This will map keys like <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, and <kbd>u</kbd> to silent versions of their default funcitons.

***Note**: that the `<silent>` part makes the mapping silent when it runs, while the `:silent` part makes the actual right-hand side run silently. This is a library; please keep your voice down.*

***Note**: the `!` in `normal!` makes it ignore mappings so you don't end up with infinite recursion.*

Here's a sample of how you can do it in Lua for Neovim as well.

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', 'p', ':silent normal! p<CR>', { silent = true })
-- ...
```